# Why my elasticsearch field automatic to utc time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

My logstash get mysql data to elasticsearch while when got the filed which the value like '2018-12-25 02:00:22' but the result in elasticsearch it be changed like 2018-12-25T08:00:22.000Z.
I don't want this. I just want to save the to elasticsearch like '2018-12-25 02:00:22'

Comment: If you are mapping your date column then it will change to "2018-12-25T08:00:22.000Z" . It's default date format of ES. If you dont want to change then dont map it.

Comment: it seems like logstash do this.

Comment: This what? If you need to have a date in es to request it, es have to index it in his format, you cant change that. But if you need to have your date in another format (for unknown reason) you can store in in a second field as a string (without index it).